# Fetch the value of the toggle button using Angular4/bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

How do i get the value of the radio button which is clicked using Angularjs 4

I tried using `ngModel` but not able to get the value.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'button-view',
  template: `
  <div class="btn-group" id="status" data-toggle="buttons" (click)="actionBtnClick()">
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-on btn-xs active">
    <input type="radio" [value]="1" name="status" checked="checked" [(ngModel)]="status">ON</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-off btn-xs">
    <input type="radio" [value]="0" name="status" [(ngModel)]="status">OFF</label>
  </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
    .btn-info{
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .btn-default.btn-on.active{background-color: #5BB75B;color: white;}
    .btn-default.btn-off.active{background-color: #DA4F49;color: white;}

`],
})
export class ButtonViewComponent implements ViewCell, OnInit {
  status: any = 1;
  constructor() {}
  actionBtnClick() {
    console.log('inside'+ status);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added answer pls check and let me know.

Comment: Also you have to change your active class when clicking a button to change background color.First try this answer and i will try next active class thing

Answer (score 0):

I did some small changes of your code here is an example from your code working,

```
status: any = 1;
actionBtnClick() {
      console.log('inside', this.status);
}
```

In typescript if you want to access declared variable as public then you have to use **this keyword**.

[image]

let try this once and let me know.

Comment: karan, I am always getting value one(1) if click on 'on' or 'off'